Solana Validator RPC port 8899 not open
I have a Solana validator, and the configured RPC port of 8899 is not open.
netstat -tulnp shows  no service listening on port 8899. Details:
Configs:
validator.sh:
#!/bin/bash

exec /home/solana/.local/share/solana/install/active_release/bin/solana-validator \
  --identity /var/solana/data/config/validator-keypair.json \
  --ledger /mnt/ledger \
  --rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0 \
  --rpc-port 8899 \
  --dynamic-port-range 8000-8020 \
  --entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 \
  --no-voting \
  --log /home/solana/solana-rpc.log \
  --full-rpc-api

solana.service:
[Unit]
Description=Solana RPC Node
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
User=solana
LimitNOFILE=1000000
ExecStart=/home/solana/bin/validator.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

IPTables Rules:
sudo iptables -L -n -v

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 55329 packets, 385M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8899
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpts:8000:8020
   18  2880 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpts:8000:8020

Log Files:
sudo journalctl -u solana -f

Jul 28 20:38:02 scfsnsolnode01 validator.sh[16986]: error: Invalid value for '--dynamic-port-range <MIN_PORT-MAX_PORT>': Port range is too small.  Try --dynamic-port-range 8000-8014
Jul 28 20:38:02 scfsnsolnode01 systemd[1]: solana.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 28 20:38:02 scfsnsolnode01 systemd[1]: solana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 28 20:38:03 scfsnsolnode01 systemd[1]: solana.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jul 28 20:38:03 scfsnsolnode01 systemd[1]: Stopped solana.service - Solana RPC Node.
Jul 28 20:38:03 scfsnsolnode01 systemd[1]: solana.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 28 20:38:03 scfsnsolnode01 systemd[1]: solana.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 28 20:38:03 scfsnsolnode01 systemd[1]: Failed to start solana.service - Solana RPC Node.
Jul 28 20:40:26 scfsnsolnode01 systemd[1]: Started solana.service - Solana RPC Node.
Jul 28 20:40:26 scfsnsolnode01 validator.sh[17049]: log file: /home/solana/solana-rpc.log

Netstat Output:
sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 8899

root@scfsnsolnode01 ~ #

Despite these settings, I am unable to connect to the RPC port. Additional troubleshooting steps tried:
Checking Local Ports:

nc -zv localhost 42136
nc -zv localhost 42138

Both return "Connection refused."

Using lsof:
sudo lsof -i :8899


Shows established connections but no listening service on the local port.

Please read your log files:

Jul 28 20:38:02 scfsnsolnode01 validator.sh[16986]: error: Invalid value for '--dynamic-port-range <MIN_PORT-MAX_PORT>': Port range is too small.  Try --dynamic-port-range 8000-8014

This should be fairly close to standard English in my opinion; you need to specify a larger range. Refer to the manual for details.
Normally errors stops things from working completely, whilst warnings may provide reduced functionality. In this case, the next log entry makes it clear that startup failed. Thus RPC is unavailable as well...
Second, you expect ports 8000-8014, why are you testing ports 42136 and 42138?
